# cannot convert numpy tuple to list

Tags: python, list, numpy, pandas

I am trying to find positions of all max len values in a column of Pandas Dataframe:

```
x2=np.where(tpo2.a.map(len) == tpo2.a.map(len).max())
```

This work and gives me tuple:

```
x2
Out[178]:
(array([34, 35], dtype=int64),)
```

I would like to find positions of the max that is closes to the position "mid point". This works:

```
min(x2, key=lambda x:abs(x-midpoint))
```

but I need x2 to be list not tuple. I tried .tolist(), list(x2), map(list,x2), but cannot get list from x2.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: why `x2 = list(x2)` didn't work? `list(x2)` is returning a `list` , maybe you forgot to assgin that to `x2`

Comment: `x2` is an array INSIDE a tuple.  You've got to use `[0]` indexing to get at the array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need the first part of x2, because np.where returns a tuple :

```
min(list(x2[0]), key=lambda x:abs(x-midpoint))
```